# How are source addresses replaced in packets responding to external hosts of a K8S cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, masquerade

[Experiments with ExternalIP in Kubernetes networking 101 - (Basic) External access into the cluster](https://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/kubernetes-networking-101-basic-external-access-into-the-cluster/) emphasize that when response packets from the cluster's external hosts are returned from ubuntu2, replace the source address with 169.10 .10.1

The original source is:
It is not possible to reverse a DNAT pointing to a pod if the request does not return that host. In this case, reversing the DNAT means changing the source of the packet back to the original pre-DNAT source of 169.10.10.1. So, as you can see, the masquerading rules are very important to ensure that the external IP structure works properly.
[image]

I also did this experiment, but I'm not sure how **masquerade** can replace the source address with 169.10.10.1?

[What is Masquerading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466445/what-is-masquerade-in-the-context-of-iptables)

- All computers appear to have the same IP
- This is done with Network Adress Translation
- It’s easy to fake the “outgoing packet”
- “Incoming packets” must be translated too
- Port translation - a must

For example, this command

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The packet goes out of **interface ppp0**, then the source address is replaced with the ip address of ppp0.

But **169.10.10.1 is actually a virtual address and does not belong to any interface on node**, so **how can masquerade replace the source address with 169.10.10.1**?